# Is the film Yesterday (2019) a remake of Jean-Philippe (2006)?

Tags: yesterday, jean-philippe

The plot from the film **Yesterday** *(2019)* is said to be:

> "After a freak bus *accident* during a mysterious global blackout, Jack
>   wakes up in another world, where [The Beatles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Beatles) do not exist."

and the plot for the film **Jean-Philippe** *(2006)* is:

> After an *accident*, Fabrice, a fan of [Johnny Hallyday](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnny_Hallyday), falls into a
>   coma. He wakes up in a parallel dimension in which Johnny, real name
>   Jean-Philippe Smet, abandoned his singing career early on and never
>   became a star.

In the [trailer from Jean-Philippe](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RnN3tT1Utxs), and in the [trailer from Yesterday](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ry9honCV3qc), both main characters are seen realizing their idols are unknown to others. In both movies, the main character struggles to make the songs they used to know a reality.

Both films being European, I wonder if Yesterday's British screenwriter has acknowledged using a similar plot to the French film. I couldn't find such statements in interviews.

Comment: It seems unlikely the writers of *Yesterday* (both of whom are very well known) would acknowledge any such influence as this would suggest plagarism.

Comment: It's very easy to either buy rights and make a remake or ask for permission to adapt loosely. I find hard to believe that in the 2+/- years it takes to write a screenplay no one close to the writer had seen a connection. No writer wants to admit their idea isn't original but a good one will do some research... Lots of films steal ideas left and right and don't always give credit (See [Avatar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aquablue#Avatar) note here for example).

Comment: Being British, it's more likely they got the idea from [this scene from Doctor Who](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u4SEDzynMiQ) that describes pretty much the same thing, but with Beethoven.

Comment: @F1Krazy that's funny, but this scene in Dr Who is also ten years after the French film came out. Must be a popular French film in the UK!

Comment: As a fellow Brit myself, I have never heard of *Jean-Philippe* and I can guarantee you that virtually nobody else here has heard of it either. I think "parallel dimension where X does not exist" is just a popular story concept in general.

Comment: @F1Krazy I think you mean **"Parallel dimension where after he has an accident the world in which X lives doesn't know Y anymore but X does"**. In any case, check out Jean-Philippe if you find subtitles, it's pretty funny!

Comment: I keep finding "French" articles that google translates for me into English that all say/suggest it's a remake, but there's no deeper evidence I can find [yet] from the EPs/Writers/Director to give you a definitive source. I can give one of the French articles though: https://www.avoir-alire.com/yesterday-danny-boyle-s-offre-un-remake-de-jean-philippe-sans-johnny-hallyday-et-les-beatles

Comment: __Yesterday__ has actually been compared to the (also british) sitcom __[Goodnight Sweetheart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodnight_Sweetheart_(TV_series)#Plot_summary)__ (1993-1999), in which the protagonist time-travels to the 1940s, where he passes off music by The Beatles as his own.